# Prevent Mule Studio from removing "invalid" properties

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm having to use a "storePrefix" property in a collection aggregator because of [Multiple Collection Aggregators in Mule causing routes to get mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960052/multiple-collection-aggregators-in-mule-causing-routes-to-get-mixed-up) which works great.  But Mule Studio doesn't think the property is valid and sometimes after I'm in the graphical view (Message Flow tab) it silently removes all the storePrefix properties for me.... how do I prevent MuleStudio from doing that?  Is there a place I can add it to a valid list of properties?

Comment: It seems this bug http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-78 has been closed prematurely: you may want to re-open it.